# Sound & Mike stopped working

Tags: sound, kernel, dell, microphone

After upgading to kernel 5.3.0-42-generic sound stopped working and same with mike. please advise.

```
root@pulakesi:/etc/modprobe.d# lspci -nnk | grep -i audio -A3
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8]
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0960]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

using dell inspiron 7391 2-in-1 laptop

Comment: Could be this Bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1837828   In eoan a kernel upgrade come's in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. which kernel version should i be upgrading too

Comment: back my pardon, you have the kernel on your system.  Please try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219214/dummy-audio-output-after-upgrade-18-04-4-hda-intel-pch

Comment: This is resolved with update to kernel uname -r
5.3.0-43-generic