# Dummy audio output after upgrade (18.04.4, HDA Intel PCH)

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After the most recent upgrade to kernel 4.15.0-91, I lost my sound. The built-in HDA Intel PCH is recognized by the kernel (as seen in the kernel log), but not shown in Settings/Sound (only Dummy Output is shown). The module snd_hda_intel is loaded, as reported by `lsmod`:

```
    snd_hda_intel          45056  4
    snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
    snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
    snd_pcm                98304  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
    snd                    81920  30 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

`lspci -nnk` also reports the PCH device (in addition to NVIDIA):

```
    00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:9b22]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    --
    01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f1] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP106 High Definition Audio Controller [1043:8641]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

I tried reinstalling `pulseaudio` and `alsa-base`, reloading `alsa`, and removing ~/.config/pulse/*, as advised in several other posts. Nothing works.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the update to 5.3.0-42, I found the solution in [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update)

To temporarily fix it you can downgrade the kernel or add the boot parameter `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0`, in the link you will found the info and links to solve it.